# how do instantiate GameObject as child of a selected object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn

I want to instantiate a game object as a child of the selected object. need help
right now I'm using this `Instantiate(EnemyPrefab[Random.Range(0, EnemyPrefab.Length)], SpwanPos, Quaternion.identity);`

Comment: `Instantiate(EnemyPrefab[Random.Range(0, EnemyPrefab.Length)],  SpwanPos, Quaternion.identity, selectedObject.transform);` ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to instantiate an object (Source: [InstantiateChildObject](https://www.monkeykidgc.com/2020/12/tips-and-tricks-unity-instantiate-prefab-as-child-of-gameobject.html))

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original);

public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);

public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent, bool instantiateInWorldSpace);

public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);

public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
```

If you would like to instantiate the prefab as a child of GameObject in world space, then:

```
GameObject childGameObject = Instantiate(yourPrefab, parentOfObject, true);
childGameObject.name = "Enemy01";
```

Do not forget to reset the transforms after it is parented (Or set your own transform)

A list of functions for all types of instantiating as child:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateAsChild : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Transform parent;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Quaternion rotation;

    public void childInstantiate()
    {
        GameObject childGameObject = Instantiate(prefab);
        childGameObject.name = "Instantiate";
    }

    public void childInstantiateAsChild()
    {
        GameObject childGameObject = Instantiate(prefab, parent);
        childGameObject.name = "InstantiateChild";

    }

    public void childInstantiateAsChildWorldSpace()
    {
        GameObject childGameObject = Instantiate(prefab, parent, true);
        childGameObject.name = "InstantiateWorldSpace";
    }

    public void childInstantiateWithPositionRotation()
    {
        GameObject childGameObject = Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation);
        childGameObject.name = "InstantiatePosAndRot";
    }
    public void childInstantiateAsChildWithPositionRotation()
    {
        GameObject childGameObject = Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation ,parent);
        childGameObject.name = "InstantiateChildPosAndRot";
    }

}
```